# Unable to create new flutter project on terminal

Tags: flutter, dart, terminal

After few mounts I tried to create new project on terminal but it's not going till end and show me this error message:

```
Image File not found E:\my_project\web\icons\Icon-maskable-192.png
```

Also has same problem when use VPN. and
there is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlhU3.jpg) from my code.

Comment: did it create any files/folders in `E:\my_project`? like `lib\main.dart` for example?

Comment: yes, create some folders and files but it's not complete. @pskink

Comment: how do you now it is "not complete"? tried to run `flutter run` command inside `E:\my_project`? if so, what are the errors you see on the console?

Comment: thank you. after open project with vs code and download some packages finally got complete! @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the screenshot, You are using Windows I think.

press `Ctrl+Shift+p`. There you can select a new Flutter project.

Comment: Is it working now @mahDyarZ